# Permissions Notification Push

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, push-notification, ionic3

Implement push notifications in iOS with firebase and everything works very well if I install the application like this:

```
ionic cordova run ios -l -c -s
```

Ask for the permissions and also send the notifications correctly. However, when I install the application from Xcode, I do not receive the alert for the permissions, nor do I receive the notifications. From the Firebase console, I do not get any error either.

Comment: Are permissions proper in plist file in xCode ?

Comment: Apparently if, as I mentioned, if I execute the application in the other way, I receive the notifications without problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note for users of Xcode 8 and higher.
If you're using the latest version of Xcode, you will likely need to **activate the Push Notifications capability** before your app is able to receive notifications.
To do this, simply navigate to the Capabilities section in your app's overview within Xcode and toggle Push Notifications*

**Important**: Use Auth certification(p8) instead p12 ssl

Comment: I have all that activated, the permission and the p8 certificate of apns correctly generated.

Comment: Mario, I generated the p8 certificate of APNs, I uploaded it to Firebase, possibly I need to upload it to the project in Xcode, as you say, how can I load it? Edit: 
Solved, I'm missing the certificate.

Greetings and thanks